# How to write a link to an Alfresco Share folder? (within a site)

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to create an HTTP link to a particular folder in Alfresco Share.

Alfresco Share encodes paths in a rather convoluted way:

```
thesite
http://server/share/page/site/thesite/documentlibrary

thesite/documentLibrary/somefolder/anotherfolder
http://server/share/page/site/thesite/documentlibrary#filter=path|%2Fsomefolder%2Fanotherfolder

thesite/documentLibrary/éß和ệ
http://server/share/page/site/s1/documentlibrary#filter=path|%2F%25E9%25DF%25u548C%25u1EC7

thesite/documentLibrary/a#bc/éß和ệ
http://server/share/page/site/thesite/documentlibrary#filter=path%7C%2Fa%2523bc%2F%25E9%25DF%25u548C%25u1EC7%7C
```

I suspect it is a double URLencode, with the exception of slashes which are only URLencoded once.
But I am not 100% sure.

Is there a C# library that does this encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find it easier to use the legacy `?path=` parameter for document library folder URL creation.

Using the example path `/Sample Content/∞⊕⊗¤☺☹★☆★☆★` instead of building a URL of the form

```
http://alfresco.example/share/page/site/mike/documentlibrary#filter=path%7C%2FSample%2520Content%2F%25u221E%25u2295%25u2297%25A4%25u263A%25u2639%25u2605%25u2606%25u2605%25u2606%25u2605%7C&page=1
```

you can generate one that looks like

```
https://alfresco.example/share/page/site/mike/documentlibrary?path=/Sample%20Content/%E2%88%9E%E2%8A%95%E2%8A%97%C2%A4%E2%98%BA%E2%98%B9%E2%98%85%E2%98%86%E2%98%85%E2%98%86%E2%98%85
```

So using C# you'd use `Uri.EscapeUriString()` on the path and append it to the base document library URL with `?path=`

You can see how the path parameter is interpreted in [documentlibrary.inc.ftl](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/share/src/main/resources/alfresco/templates/org/alfresco/include/documentlibrary.inc.ftl#L30-L33)

Comment: Very cool! Is it something that works across all recent Alfresco versions? If it is legacy, I guess it might get dropped very soon, or is there a particular reason to believe it will be kept for a while? Thanks!

Comment: There are no plans to remove it that I know of, although I'm no longer active on the Share team. I'll make sure the Aikau team are aware that's a feature in active use.

Answer (score 2):

Check `org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.site.SiteShareViewUrlGet`for an implementation. Its not very elegant, but seems pretty complete, probably a good starting point for your own class.

There really should be a helper class for this, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: That class is what Alfresco itself uses when it needs to find the Share URL for a given page (eg for putting in emails), so it ought to be pretty complete. It's available as `/api/sites/shareUrl?nodeRef={nodeRef}` so you can call it from the Repo or Share

Comment: Yes exactly, its a webscript - I sure don't want to call a friggin webscript for generating n urls in some Java code, but of course use a Java method call. That class does not have a suitable API.

Comment: You can call a webscript from Java, it's just another bean!

Comment: About the idea of calling Alfresco to get the URL: My client program needs to work is environment where network is a costly resource, so I would rather replicate the code to do everything on my side without calling the Alfresco server. So I'd rather use the source code of a class as Michael suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a library, so I wrote the following code:

```
if (path.Contains("documentLibrary"))
{
    int firstSlashPosition = path.IndexOf("/");
    string siteName = path.Substring(0, firstSlashPosition);
    string pathWithinSite = path.Substring(firstSlashPosition + "/documentLibrary".Length);
    string escapedPathWithinSite = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pathWithinSite);
    string reescapedPathWithinSite = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(escapedPathWithinSite);
    string sharePath = reescapedPathWithinSite.Replace("%252f", "%2F");
    return "http://server/share/page/site/" + siteName + "/documentlibrary#filter=path|" + sharePath;
}
else
{
    // Site name only.
    return "http://server/share/page/site/" + path + "/documentlibrary";
}
```

Any correction or better answer would be much appreciated!